# Google maps IOS sdk just show '??????'

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, sdk

I am using google map iOS SDK v2.0.26137.0 library in a swift project, to insert a map into a `UITableViewCell`, I followed the steps shown by google at the website, and I always got:

[image: this]

The point is that I tried:

- Create a new `UIViewController` and Storyboard independent of the rest of code but inside of the same project -> NOT works
- Be sure that I followed the steps properly and the API key is correct -> NOT WORKS
- Using a older version of Google maps SDK for IOS -> NOT Works
- Implement it in a new project just for it -> WORKS!!!

So the problem is about my project but I don't know what's the different between them. I have some libraries added to the project, but when I tried, at the first point, with an independent controller and storyboard, it shouldn't be affected for external libraries I thought.

Please if someone knows what it could happen let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding one `UIView` to the `UItableViewCell` in the **storyboard**, then assign the `GMSMapview Class` on the identity inspector to the `UIView` object.... Something like this:

[image]

It should works

Comment: That it's how I have it and it doesn't work. To simplify the problem, I tried assign  GMSMapView directly to the UIView in a simple UIViewController inside the project that I created to test it and it didn't work. Also I tried to add a UIView inside the view and neither. Could be a problem with codification characters of my app? Thanks!

Comment: Did you add **GoogleMaps** with `CocoaPods` if it is remember set the target of your project in the Podfile . Try doing a clean of the project and rebuilding it.

Comment: The target it's fine. That's the point, I have two project with (apparently) the same but in one it woks and the other not. I think could be about the project's configuration or something like that because it not just affect to one controller but  a simple UIView that I add it as GMSMapView too

Comment: What about re install The pod ?